# У меня есть два указателя на одну и ту же ячейку памяти. Как сделать так, чтобы один из них больше не указывал на нее?

Tags: c, указатели

У меня есть два указателя на одну и ту же ячейку памяти. Как сделать так, чтобы один из них больше не указывал на нее?

Comment: `odinUkazatel = NULL;`

Comment: в таком случае, значение второго указателя тоже изменяется на NULL ( проверяла в отладчике)

Comment: нет, не изменится. Проверял в голове.

Comment: В таком случае приведите пример кода, скорее всего вы что-то делаете не так или по незнанию даете неверную информацию.

Comment: да, простите, моя ошибка в другом месте